# How to migrate a dockerized gitlab service from one machine to another machine?

Tags: postgresql, docker, gitlab

I have a gitlab service that is created using a `docker-compose.yml` file like this:

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  web:
    image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:15.11.5-ce.0'
    restart: always
    hostname: 'gitlab.mydomain.com'
    environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
        nginx['listen_https'] = false
        gitlab_ci['gitlab_ci_all_broken_builds'] = true
        gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 10067
        ...
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '10067:22'
    volumes:
      - './config:/etc/gitlab'
      - './logs:/var/log/gitlab'
      - './data:/var/opt/gitlab'
    shm_size: '512m'
```

I'd like to migrate this gitlab service from linux machine A to linux machine B.

Here're the steps of the migration:

1. Run `docker-compose down` to stop the gitlab service.
2. Package the gitlab files using `zip -r mygitlab.zip mygitlab/`. `mygitlab/` is a folder that contains `docker-compose.yml`, `config/`, `data/`, and `logs/`.
   The zip command creates the following warning:

```
zip warning: No such device or address
    zip warning: could not open for reading: mygitlab/data/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

When I use `ls -la mygitlab/data/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432` to check this file. I found that it's an unix domain socket

```
$ ls -la gitlab-ce-test/data/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
srwxrwxrwx 1 996 chrony 0  8月 17 11:32 gitlab-ce-test/data/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

3. Transfer `mygitlab.zip` file from machine A to machine B using `scp` command.
4. Start the gitlab service in machine B by running `unzip mygitlab.zip && cd mygitlab && docker-compose up -d`.
5. The following log appears in `docker logs -f <gitlab_container_name>`:

```
[2023-08-17T05:28:22+00:00] INFO: Report handlers complete
Infra Phase complete, 32/763 resources updated in 11 seconds
[2023-08-17T05:28:22+00:00] WARN: This release of Cinc Client became end of life (EOL) on May 1st 2023. Please update to a supported release to receive new features, bug fixes, and security updates.
gitlab Reconfigured!
Checking for unmigrated data on legacy storage
Upgrade failed. Could not check for unmigrated data on legacy storage.




If you would like to restart the instance without performing this
check, add the following to your docker command:
-e GITLAB_SKIP_UNMIGRATED_DATA_CHECK=true
```

Then the docker container just keeps restarting.

Is the `Upgrade failed` message caused by not able to copy `.s.PGSQL.5432` to machine B?

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: It's not going to be the socket. PostgreSQL will create that on startup. That "Upgrade failed" looks suspicious though. Could it be a permission problem on the copied data?

Comment: I agree with @RichardHuxton that the socket is not a problem.  Why are you using `zip` instead of `tar` or maybe even `rsync` to move the files over to the other machine?  I ask because I do not think `zip` deals with ownership and permissions.

Comment: Hi, @RichardHuxton, @MikeOrganek. You are right. The problem is caused by wrong files/folders permission settings. After using `rsync -avz ./mygitlab/* <username>@<machine_B_ip_address>:/target/path/to/machine/b/` to copy the files and folders from machine A to machine B, I can successfully launch gitlab service in machine B.